# rails has_and_belongs_to_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following structure

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tours
end

class Tour < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
end
```

Now I want something like

```
Tour.first.countries
Country.first.tours
```

What is the best way to achieve that without creating an additional join table for countries_tours

Answer (score 1):

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities
  has_many :tours,  -> { distinct }, through: :cities
end

class Tour < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
  has_many :countries,  -> { distinct }, through: :cities
end
```

I managed it